# How to show select|unselect states for grids in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a few grids which contains button and textblock inside each grids. I have grid style like this

```
<Style x:Key="SubSection_Grid_Style" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,5"/>
</Style>
```

I want to show which grid has been tapped or selected, and after tapping another grid, it should change state back to normal. I know how to set it like

```
<Storyboard>
 <DoubleAnimation 
      Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
      Duration="0"
      To="1" />
</Storyboard>
```

but not sure how to switch between select|unselect. Any idea?

Comment: You can't do this with a Grid. Because a Grid doesn't have a select|unselect state. You should use a GridView or a ListBox to archive this.

Comment: @Nuwannnz You are right. I ended up with using setting background, I bind it to some Boolean and write a converter to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Please add your solution as a answer. so it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use the states of the grid. Try to write your own converter and bind the opacity or background to some Boolean variable.

```
    <Grid Background="{Binding IsSomeGridShow, Converter={StaticResource BooleantoOpacityOrBackgroundConverter}}" >
        <Button>
        <TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```